# MSAccess: Datasheet in a subform - Save layout changes?

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform containing a datasheet.  Occasionally, I need to adjust the datasheet layout (column order, widths, etc.).  In layout mode, even design mode, clicking SAVE does not seem to retain these changes.

However, there are certain instances where the changes ARE saved, but I am not clear what was the mechanism permitting the save.

My intent is to freeze the layout modifications, allowing my users to play with the layout at runtime, but not prompt them to SAVE at the end of their session.

Any tricks to saving these layout changes??  It's maddening!

Not:  I do not see the AllowDesignChanges property in the property sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I presume this is not impossible.

For the interim, I have resorted to using a separate table containing all table attributes names ("AttrDisplay", 135 columns, don't ask - inherited this thing), with a column per Filter (4 of them).  I set attribute order with a simple integer value, hide/unhide from columns in that table.  Depending which filter is selected by the user.

On subform Load, I hide all columns:

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    ctl.ColumnHidden = True
Next ctl
```

Then I open the "AttrDisplay" table and step thru each column to set order and unhide filter-specific columns.  Also autofit the column width:

```
strSQL = "SELECT AttrDisplay.AttrNo, AttrDisplay.AttrName, AttrDisplay.Filter1, AttrDisplay.FIlter2, AttrDisplay.Filter3, AttrDisplay.Filter4 " & _
     "FROM AttrDisplay " & _
     "WHERE (((AttrDisplay.Filter1) > 0)) " & _
     "ORDER BY AttrDisplay.Filter1;"
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rs2.EOF
    If rs2!Filter1 < 8000 Then       'Leave hidden > 8000
        Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Controls(rs2!AttrName).Properties("ColumnHidden") = False
        Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Controls(rs2!AttrName).Properties("ColumnOrder") = rs2!Filter1
        Forms![myForm]![mySubform].Form.Controls(rs2!AttrName).Properties("ColumnWidth") = -2
    End If
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
```

I modify this code based of the selected filter.  Makes modifying this unwieldy datasheet display quite configurable.  The selected filter provides a significantly different view of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the subform directly seemed to work for me, i.e. don't make changes from the main form, but rather open the subform itself and make/save changes.

This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work for me:

1. Open the form that has all of the sub-forms on it.
2. Re-arrange or size the fields in the sub-forms as you wish them to be.
3. Click on (highlight) one of the columns in the sub-form.
4. On the ribbon, in the text formatting group, center this column (or change any attribute in the text formatting group), then change it back to left justified (or Bold and then un-bold the sub-form).
5. Close and save the form when prompted.

Your sub-form should now have all of your changes.